# Cloning error Openshift Tomcat Mysql App

Tags: openshift

I am using Openshift and installed Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) and Mysql 5.5, Jenkins and PHPMyadmin. i am using free version which is basically small gears. Actually i am facing difficulty in uploading my war file every now and then. then i have to clean up the space only then it will allow me to deploy the war file.

My question is that is it the case of small gears or something else. Going for a paid plan can solve my plan or not.

Between, my application is small (30MB War) plus small DB.

Please respond

Answer (score 0):

The free account gives you three gears each with 1GB of disk space. Your application gear is hosting Tomcat, MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin cartridges so they will consume the disk space. Also, if you are storing multiple deployments than they all will consume space. Can you check the disk quota of your application? SSH into the application gear and run `quota -s` command. The paid plan offering will solve this problem because you can get more storage upto 6GB per gear. You can run `rhc tidy` command to clean out your gear as well.

Comment: ooh I see. Actually in my single gear, i have four cartridge. tomcat, phppmyadmin, mysql and jenkins. Can i install mysql  and  phpmyadmin in different gear???

Comment: Yes by creating scalable application.